# how to create dynamic tables in google bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage, jobs

I have a BigQuery database, i want to create dynamic tables daily instead of manually creating table each day.

Ex: 
tablename_20170616 - if date is 16th june 2017
tablename_20170617 - if date is 17th june 2017.

Is it possible to create dynamic tables using bigquery jobs?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably use partitioned tables instead. Partitions will be automatically created when data is loaded into it: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/partitioned-tables.

Comment: Is it possible to create dynamic tables using bigquery jobs?

Comment: A BigQuery job can create the destination table if not exist. But to create dynamic tables you'll need to give the destination table a different name every day. Or you can use the partitioned tables, then the destination table name can remain the same, and a new partition will be automatically created every day. For example, if a job finishes on 2017-06-21 UTC then its result will be appended to the 20170621 partition.

Comment: @Hua Zhang how about the pricing?

Comment: Price for storage is same as dynamic tables. When queried only partitions scanned by the query will be charged, https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables.